# Will the Taint ever overrun the bio-domes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thaumcraft

I recently started playing the Blightfall mod pack. The pack is centered around the exploration of a "tainted" world and uses Thaumcraft's Taint to achieve this. The player can enter one of several pre-generated "bio-domes", each of which contains 3 beds, a Bookshelf, and a Silverwood tree in the center.

Mirabelle Hackett, one of the NPCs, stated that the player(s) should be safe within the domes, and I have observed that it does not seem to pass through the glass that the domes are made of. However, some areas aren't blocked off. For example, at the "Beta" dome, there is an open cave with no glass covering the entrance at any point.

Am I in danger of being overrun by the Taint, or will it never seriously threaten the domes?

Comment: This is off-topic because we don't answer questions about mods.

Comment: Try ask the mod creator

Comment: @ALX Pretty sure it's on-topic. Gameplay is fine, but technical issues are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, biodomes will be safe if you don't destroy the tree with pure aura node inside.

The thing is that this **pure** [aura node](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Nodes) pushes taint back, so it holds it even if you would make a hole in a dome. Do note that the taint cannot spread on glass, so it is good to make "the door" through it one block above the terrain to be sure.

However if you would remove all the glass, it probably won't spread too much inside neither. Maybe few blocks, but more will be blocked by the Aura.

More about the taint: http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Taint